# How to update same columns on different tables at the same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have `Table-A` with a column called `serial_number`, and `Table-B` has the same column.

Update a single table is not possible to their linkage, upon attempt though, this is the error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "L_231". The conflict occurred in
>   database "Main", table "dbo.Products".
>   The statement has been terminated.

I know how I can delete the field in both in case I need to, I just don't know how to update it simultaneously.

Thanks.

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566494/foreign-key-constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**this is a BAD design.** if this isn't a "one time thing" to fix an issue, but part of your applicaion, you need a redesign.

You shouldn't update keys, use a surrogate key (like an identity) instead and then store the `serial_number` as a plain data column (which can be easily changed).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the constraint as `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello**

> Good question but ????
>
> one Method is Update trigger
>
> you update in same time on different table