# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In my project I am filling two database tables with two DataSets. The method which I am using to fill those database tables is shown  below:

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();            
SqlCommand command;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdReset = new SqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('Doctor', RESEED, 0)", conn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdUnCheck = new SqlCommand("alter table [dbo].[Doctor] nocheck constraint all",conn))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmdCheck = new SqlCommand("alter table [dbo].[Doctor] with check check constraint all",conn))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
                    cmd.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
                    cmdReset.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
                    cmdUnCheck.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
                    cmdCheck.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
                    try
                    {
                        cmdUnCheck.ExecuteNonQuery();
           /*ERROR*/    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmdReset.ExecuteNonQuery();//deleting database table data
                        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) //Inserting new data into the Database table
                        {
                            command = new SqlCommand(query.createDoctorRow("Doctor",
                            dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), Convert.ToInt64(dr[3]), Convert.ToInt32(dr[4])), conn, sqlTransaction);
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        cmdCheck.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlTransaction.Commit();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        sqlTransaction.Rollback();
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }                
}
```

The above code was working fine till the second Database table was empty but when I inserted some data in it and then run the code, VS is showing error -->

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Dr_ID". The conflict occurred in database "Hospital", table "dbo.Patient", column 'Doctor_ID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

This seems clear that the foreign key is restricting the query to take place but as I am a beginner and dont know what to do I am asking your help..

In the above code I made changes referring to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1566552/1577396) but no joy, the error still exists at the same point.

*Optional*: Is there anyway to reduce the `using` statements in my code?

Comment: @m4tt1mus The code you've posted is not really clear. Did you know that you may post codes at [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) as well? Have a great day :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [I got error “The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776269/i-got-error-the-delete-statement-conflicted-with-the-reference-constraint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't delete the data in the DOCTOR table since you have a relation to the Patient table via the Id of the DOCTOR.

Comment: Then how to delete it.. I did `no check` but no use. I need to delete the table.

Comment: please explain how to remove the relation. I am new to c# and SQL

Comment: yes this link is very much helpful it solved my problem. :) Thank you

Comment: @theprogrammer as the link is broken, answer is mystery now

Comment: New link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/delete-foreign-key-relationships